# Create hiscore list from hiscore table 

Tags: sql-server

I want to create hiscore list, but I have trouble doing it. This is my hiscore table and for every game I write user score into this table.

This is how my hiscore table look like:

```
id    user_id    user_name    score    entry_date
-----------------------------------------------------------
1      1         tom          500      2012-06-05 14:30:00
2      1         tom          500      2012-06-05 10:25:00
3      2         jim          300      2012-06-05 09:20:00
4      2         jim          500      2012-06-05 09:22:00
5      3         tony         650      2012-06-05 15:45:00
```

I want to get first 3 MAX scores, but I have to make sure if they have same score then I should take score that is first entered (based on `entry_date` column)

The query returned should be something like this.

```
1.  3      tony     650      2012-06-05 15:45:00     <- hi have to be first, because he have top score
2.  2      jim      500      2012-06-05 09:22:00     <- jim have the same score as tom, but he make that score before tom did so he is in second place
3.  1      tom      500      2012-06-05 10:25:00     <- tom have 2 entries with the same score, but we only take the one with smallest date
```

This is SQL query that I wrote but with that query i am getting hiscore list but it's not ordered by entry_date and I don't have any idea how to solve this problem.

```
SELECT TOP 3
    hiscore.user_id,
    hiscore.user_name,
    MAX(hiscore.score) AS max_score,
FROM
    hiscore
GROUP BY
    hiscore.user_id, hiscore.user_name
ORDER BY
    max_score DESC
```

### UPDATE: Regarding score sum question

Regarding score sum, I need query that will return this when querying original hiscore table:

```
user_id   user_name    score
--------------------------------
1          Tom        1000
2          Jim         800
3          Tony        650
```

And if there are two users with the same score sum, user with better rank is the one with less entries in hiscore table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** this first query is a lie and won't work! :), assuming sql 2005+ use the second one

Just add EntryDate to your order by

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    hiscore.user_id, 
    hiscore.user_name, 
    MAX(hiscore.score) AS max_score, 
FROM 
    hiscore 
GROUP BY 
    hiscore.user_id, hiscore.user_name 
ORDER BY 
    max_score DESC, entry_date DESC
```

Edit: ah I didn't even see the group by - forget that, hang on a sec!

This one :P

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT
    hiscore.user_id,
    hiscore.user_name,
    hiscore.score,
    hiscore.entry_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_id ORDER BY Score DESC, entry_date) as scoreNo
FROM 
    hiscore 
) as highs WHERE ScoreNo = 1 ORDER BY Score DESC, entry_date
```

assuming SQL 2005+

Edit:

In order to get the best scores ordered by score and then by number of entries the query is a bit simpler:

```
SELECT user_id, user_name, SUM(score) as Score from hiscore
GROUP BY user_id, user_name
ORDER BY sum(score) DESC, count(score)
```

This will give you the scores ordered by the sum of 'score' descending, and then ordered by number of entries ascending which should give you what you want

Comment: Thank you this is it. Can you write SQL query if I have the same table but I am not looking for hiscore, but rather score SUM for each user. So I would like to get list of the best score SUMS. If you know what I mean.

Comment: I have updated my answer  to find out the best score of an individual user

Comment: I've just updated my question regarding score sum list. I would really appreciate if you could please help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
;with cte as 
(Select id ,userID,score,entry_date,row_number() over(partition by userID
 order by score desc,entry_date) as row_num from Score
)
Select * from cte where row_num=1 ORDER BY Score DESC,entry_date 

// sum of score  for individual user 
Select  UserID,sum(Score) from Score
group by UserID
```

Result in [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6417f/1/0)

Comment: It works because it's exactly the same answer as mine just in a different order :D